# How can I check if the server is running on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dart

I need to check if the server is running on app engine.

Something like this:

```
if (canRunAppEngine) {
    runAppEngine(app.handleRequest);
} else {
    app.start();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify environment variables and then check in your Dart code whether it is set

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables

**app.yaml**

```
env_variables:
  IS_APPENGINE: 'true'
```

in Dart

```
if(Platform.environment['IS_APPENGINE'] == 'true') {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One checks for a value of environment variable `com.google.appengine.runtime.environment`, which is either `"Production"` or `"Development"`. If it is `null` instead, you are not running App Engine.

I think following should do the job:

```
if(Platform.environment['com.google.appengine.runtime.environment'] != null) {
   ...
}
```

Note: in Java one normally uses `SystemProperty.environment.value()` to check for the value. I have no experience with Dart, I hope someone working with it can confirm if the above works or not.